# Running Assembly programs in command prompt w/ windows 7

Tags: assembly, cmd

I was wondering how to run debug in command prompt in Windows 7. I have looked this up online, finding only that you can find the debug.exe in the System32 file, but it is not. If this is not possible, is there any other comparable program for compiling and editing Assembly programs?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Comment: `debug.exe` is not a very nice assembler; e.g. it doesn't even support labels for jump targets.  https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/debug.htm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't compile Assembly code, you Assemble and optionally Link.

Popular Assemblers:

- [MASM/MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/)
- [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/)
- [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/)
- [JWASM](http://www.japheth.de/JWasm.html)
- [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/)
- [GoASM](http://www.godevtool.com/)
- [PoASM](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/)

Many are able to Assemble 32 or 64 bit instructions.  All will run on Windows 7.  I think all will also Assemble 16 bit code, but 16bit DOS apps will not run on Windows 7 without a DOS emulator.  You could use [D-Fend Reloaded](http://dfendreloaded.sourceforge.net/) which is a DOSBox Frontend and works well.
A good free debugger is [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/)

To edit Assembler source files, all you need is notepad really.  You could use Visual Studio.  I use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) on Windows and Linux.  There is also [RadASM v2](https://fbedit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/fbedit/RadASM/ReleaseMake/Release.zip) which is a good free IDE for with a resource editor, also [RadASM v3](https://fbedit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/fbedit/RadASM30/Release/RadASM.zip).  [WinASM](http://www.winasm.net/winasm-studio-downloads.html) is also a decent Assembly IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is not possible, is there any other comparable program for compiling and editing Assembly programs?

Here is a [32-bit assembler](http://www.masm32.com) that might work.  And here is a [64-bit assembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx), it looks like it comes bundled with visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: http://www.kerrywong.com/2009/05/08/ms-debug-1981-2009/ there is some replacement:

64-bit
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx

32-bit
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.mspx

Answer (score -1):

I use MASM32 SDK. For performance out of this world.